# postgresql - psql always goes to port 5432, even when 2 versions of postgresql are running

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have 2 versions of postgresql running on Suse SLES, 9.6 and 10.7.  The 9.6 version is running on port 5432, and 10.7 is running on port 5433.  All the executables for each version are in the directory for that version, including psql.

If I execute the default psql, I get psql for version 9.6.3:

```
psql (9.6.3)
```

However, when I try to execute psql for version 10.7:

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql
```

it opens the version for 10.7, but reading from postgresql 9.6.3:

```
psql (10.7, Server 9.6.3).
```

If I try to give it the port number for 10.7:

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql -p 5433
```

it demands a password, but rejects the password for the user postgres that I know works in other contexts.

I have spent considerable time searching for an answer to this question, and I am sorry I have not found anything helpful.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried setting env variables or pgpass files for handling the credentials?

Comment: I just tried export PGPORT=5433, and then /usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql.  It still demands the password, and rejects postgres's password.

Comment: setting a pgpass file also does not help.  It demands the port number for running psql for 10.7, (unlike PGPORT - with that set, it needs no additional port number) .  When I add the port number, then it requires I enter the password, then rejects it with the accustomed "FATAL: Password authentication for user postgres failed"

Comment: When  you installed the 10.7 version did you update the password for the database user `postgres` in it? By default a `postgres` user will be added to new install, but without a password.  You probably need to do `ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD`. To get to that point you will need to alter `pg_hba.conf` to allow a connection using `trust` instead of `password`.

Comment: "but rejects the password for the user postgres that I know works in other contexts."  What specifically are those other contexts?

Comment: pgpass is a file.  It is incapable of making demands.

Comment: What does `/usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql -p 5433 -U postgres` do?

Comment: Wow, thanks, everyone, for the ideas. @MikeOrganek: postgres@platon:~> /usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql -p 5433 -U postgres
Passwort für Benutzer postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  Passwort-Authentifizierung für Benutzer »postgres« fehlgeschlagen
postgres@platon:~> /usr/pgsql-10/bin/psql -p 5433 -U postgres
Passwort für Benutzer postgres: 
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: @jjanes: another context: as another user, I su to postgres: su - postgres    This requires a password, and the password that works here, does not work when psql wants/demands a password.

Comment: @jjanes pgpass should provide the port and password for the operation, similar to the environment variable PGPORT (which only provides the port number).  If the password is not provided from pgpass, psql wants/demands a password.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this is the answer - if you would post it as an answer, I will endorse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in play here.

1)

> I su to postgres: su - postgres This requires a password, and the password that works here, does not work when psql wants/demands a password.

The OS `postgres` user is not the same as the database `postgres` user.

2. On a fresh install the database `postgres` user does not have a password. Generally speaking the `auth` method for the user is set to either `trust`, `ident` or `peer`. See here [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) what they mean. The key to a solution is to modify the `pg_hba.conf` to allow the user to connect in order to be able to create a password. The easiest way is to set a connection method, best practice `local`(socket) to `trust`. Then you can connect without a password and create one.